# I need a way to accept UPPERCASE letters only

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf

I need a way to accept UPPERCASE letters only and I want to use ELSE to print an error (or the other way around) for the reason of having fun with run length encoding, but it seems to not work.

Every time I enter even a single character, like A or B - it spits out the error.

This is not what the code really looks like, the IF and ELSE statements are what matters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char current, previous = 0;
    int AoR = 0, unc_am, am, first = 0;

    while(scanf("%c", &current) != EOF)
    {
        if(current <= 'Z' && current >= 'A')
        {RLE}
        else
        {printf error}
    }
}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You might take a look at function `isupper()` declared in `ctype.h`. C does not define to have no gaps between letters.

Comment: @kiranBiradar please fix your comment, it has a couple of errors in the code

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thank you! `scanf("%c", &current)`-->`scanf(" %c", &current)`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks, that's a nice time saver for the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
scanf("%c", &current);
```

to:

```
scanf(" %c", &current)
```

as commented by @kiranBiradar. I had summed up the reason for this in [Caution when reading char with scanf](https://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/caution-when-reading-char-with-scanf-c/).

PS: You could use [`isupper()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isupper/), which checks if a character is uppercase, as @gerhardh commented.

Comment: Thank you! That was it, now I can focus on the RLE itself, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must check for and skip over line terminators. They are characters too...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char c;
  while (scanf ("%c", &c) == 1)
    {
      printf("0x%02X ", c);
      if (c == '\n')
        printf("\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Running:

```
ABC
0x41 0x42 0x43 0x0A
DefG
0x44 0x65 0x66 0x47 0x0A
H
0x48 0x0A
i
0x69 0x0A
```